# Java: How to reverse a number of strings using "import.java.util.*;" that is User Dependent?

Tags: java, string, user-input, reverse

i already had a program.. but the only thing i want to add is reverse it.. i used one class.. and one is the main class..

main class:

public maonajudni() {
    }

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);     
    System.out.println("Enter how many stringz");
    int x = in.nextInt(); 

    String applearray[] = new String[x];    

    for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++){

    applearray[i] = in.next();   
    }
    nospance gstonako = new nospance();      
    gstonako.sortme(applearray , x);  
    gstonako.uppervowel(applearray , x);  


}
```

}

this is the class:

class nospance {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}   
    public void sortme(String s[] , int y){
    String tmp="";
    for(int j = 0 ; j < y ; j++){
        for(int k = 0 ; k < y ; k++){
            if(s[j].compareToIgnoreCase(s[k])<1){
                tmp = s[j];
                s[j] = s[k];
                s[k] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

public void uppervowel(String arr[] , int z){

```
    String tmp = "";

    for(int j = 0 ; j < z ; j++){
        System.out.println("");
        for(int k = 0 ; k < arr[j].length() ; k++){

            if(arr[j].charAt(k)=='A' || arr[j].charAt(k)=='a'){
                tmp = tmp + arr[j].charAt(k);
                System.out.print(""+tmp.toUpperCase());
                tmp = "";

            }
            else if(arr[j].charAt(k)=='E' || arr[j].charAt(k)=='e'){

            tmp = tmp + arr[j].charAt(k);
                System.out.print(""+tmp.toUpperCase());
                tmp = "";


        }
        else if(arr[j].charAt(k)=='I' || arr[j].charAt(k)=='i'){

            tmp = tmp + arr[j].charAt(k);
                System.out.print(""+tmp.toUpperCase());
                tmp = "";

    }
    else if(arr[j].charAt(k)=='O' || arr[j].charAt(k)=='o'){

                tmp = tmp + arr[j].charAt(k);
                System.out.print(""+tmp.toUpperCase());
                tmp = "";

}
else if(arr[j].charAt(k)=='U' || arr[j].charAt(k)=='u'){

            tmp = tmp + arr[j].charAt(k);
                System.out.print(""+tmp.toUpperCase());
                tmp = "";
```

}
    else{

```
     System.out.print(""+ arr[j].charAt(k));

}
        }

    }
```

}
}

this is already a running program. can someone help me add reverse the inputted strings? please and thank you. I used JCreator Pro and jdk 1.7.0.

Comment: why not use `StringBuilder.reverse()` to reverse a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standart Java libraries

```
String str = "abcd";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
System.out.println(sb.reverse());
```

or you can write your own function

```
private static String reverse(String s) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = s.length(); i > 0; --i) {
        result.append(s.charAt(i - 1));
    } 

    return result.toString();
}
```